# How to deserialize json string to object list in c# dot

Tags: c#, .net, json, desktop-application

I am working with the following JSON string

```
{
"transactions": 
[
   {
    "paymentcharge":"0.0",
    "amount":352,
    "id":13418,
    "shippingcharge":35,
    "shippingtype":2,
    "status":2,
    "paymenttype":1,
    "date":"2012-10-06 16:15:28.0"
   },   
   {
    "paymentcharge":"0.0",
    "amount":42455,
    "id":16305,
    "shippingcharge":0,
    "shippingtype":2,
    "status":2,
    "paymenttype":2,
    "date":"2012-11-30 09:29:29.0"
   },   
   {
    "paymentcharge":"1.0",
    "amount":42456,
    "id":16305,
    "shippingcharge":0,
    "shippingtype":2,
    "status":2,
    "paymenttype":2,
    "date":"2012-11-30 09:29:29.0"
   }
],
"count":3
}
```

---

I have a class structure as follows for parsing and feeling the json data

```
class clsSalesTran
{
    public double paymentcharge { get; set; }
    public double amount { get; set; }
    public long id { get; set; }
    public int shippingcharge { get; set; }
    public int shippingtype { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
    public int paymenttype { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
}
```

---

How can I deserialize the above JSON string into List ?

> I am using *Newtonsoft.Json* for deserialize.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

first create another class:

```
public class SalesTransactions
{
     public List<clsSalesTran> transactions {get;set;}
     public int count{get;set;}
}
```

Then use,

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SalesTransactions>(inputString)
```

Comment: Is the count property necessary? Not in my experience.

Comment: @gusmallysupportsMonica, Wheather the `count` property is necessary, is not relevant to question. The objective of the question was deserialization of incoming JSON string

Comment: right, but if I had asked this question, I would assume that your answer would give what was required and nothing more. As we know, it's good practice to omit needless code. FWIW I upvoted your question, but left a comment for subsequent visitors who may be wondering the same thing.

Comment: isnt it more cleaner to do `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SalesTransactions>>(inputString)` then you won't need the extra class ?

Comment: @Jessedegans Do note that `List<clsSalesTran>` is only the inner list of the whole JSON object. `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SalesTransactions>>(inputString)` would only work if the input string is only the list

Comment: @gusmallysupportsMonica you might have missed the "count" property at the end of the json.

Comment: @djones you're right; I totally did. Sorry Satpal I misunderstood what you were saying.

Answer (score 12):

Create a class as below
By creating the list of class 'clsSalesTran' and a variable for 'Count'

**Note: JsonProperty is mandatory from your Json String**

```
public class SalesTransactions
{
     [JsonProperty("transactions")]
     public List<clsSalesTran> transactions {get;set;}
     public int count{get;set;}
}
```

Then you may use this class as below to deserialize

```
SalesTransactions st = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SalesTransactions>(inputString)
```

Use the Deserialized object as below

```
double paymentcharge = st.transactions[0].paymentcharge;
```

Answer (score 8):

To deserialize a string to a `List` of objects of type `clsSalesTran`:

```
var myList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<clsSalesTran>>(inputString);
```

Comment: Note: this will not work for the JSON in the original question. This will only work if the entirety of the JSON being parsed in `inputString` is only an unnamed array.

Answer (score -1):

```
class WeapsCollection
{
    public Dictionary<string, WeaponDetails> Weapons { get; set; }

}

class WeaponList
{
    public WeaponDetails AEK { get; set; }
    public WeaponDetails XM8 { get; set; }
}

class WeaponDetails
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Kills { get; set; }
    public int Shots_Fired { get; set; }
    public int Shots_Hit { get; set; }
}

class Program  
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"
        {
           'weapons':

                    {
                       'aek':
                            {
                               'name':'AEK-971 Vintovka',
                               'kills':47,
                               'shots_fired':5406,
                               'shots_hit':858
                            },
                       'xm8':
                            {
                               'name':'XM8 Prototype',
                               'kills':133,
                               'shots_fired':10170,
                               'shots_hit':1790
                            },
                    }

        }";

        WeapsCollection weps = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeapsCollection>(json);
        Console.WriteLine(weps.Weapons.First().Value.Shots_Fired);            

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Reply back in case of any issues.