# deserialize index based json object - c#

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I am using Newtonsoft and Newtonsoft.Json. I have the below json:

```
string strJson_StorageInfo = "[{10:\"test\"}, {20:\"test1\"}]";

List<Dictionary<int, string>> jobj = (List<Dictionary<int, string>>) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strJson_StorageInfo, typeof(List<Dictionary<int, string>>));
foreach (Dictionary<int, string> dicStorageInfo in jobj) {
   foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> StorageItem in dicStorageInfo) {
      Response.Write("key : " + StorageItem.Key + " , value : " + StorageItem.Value + "</br>"); 
   }
}
```

I need to Deserialize this. Can anyone suggest me good method. Thanks in advance

Comment: I only see a string here, no usage of Newtonsoft. Are you serializing the JSON above?

Comment: List<Dictionary<int, string>> jobj = (List<Dictionary<int, string>>) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strJson_StorageInfo, typeof(List<Dictionary<int, string>>));

foreach (Dictionary<int, string> dicStorageInfo in jobj)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> StorageItem in dicStorageInfo)
                {
                    Response.Write("key : " + StorageItem.Key + " , value : " + StorageItem.Value + "</br>");
                }
            }

i feel unnecessary enumuration on list objects and then dictionary object.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934360/how-to-deserialize-json-string-to-object-list-in-c-sharp-dot Did you try this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use below mentioned code

```
string strJson_StorageInfo = "[{10:\"test\"}, {20:\"test1\"}]";
var abc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <List<Dictionary<int, string>>>(strJson_StorageInfo);
```

after you can find the keys and Values from it

```
  var K = abc.Select(p => p.Keys);
  var V = abc.Select(p => p.Values);
```

Comment: I am using asp.net 2.0

Answer (score 0):

ok. I compromised with Json Format String. I have changed the json string. Found similar thread in [How can I deserialize JSON to a simple Dictionary<string,string> in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.. I am not sure if it works in asp.net 2.0

```
string strJson_StorageInfo = "[{10:\"test\"}, {20:\"test1\"}]";
List<Dictionary<int, string>> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<int, string>>>(strJson_StorageInfo);
foreach (var items in values)
{
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        Label1.Text += "Key: " + item.Key.ToString() + " Value: " + item.Value.ToString() + "<br/>";
    }
}
```