# C# Read Json file into memory and group by same value

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I have JSON file:

```json
{
  "DatabaseType": "Customer",
  "TableName": "Test",
  "RowsCopied": "6"
},
{
  "DatabaseType": "Customer",
  "TableName": "JDJD",
  "RowsCopied": "202"
},
{
  "DatabaseType": "Hosting",
  "TableName": "Test",
  "RowsCopied": "6"
},
{
  "DatabaseType": "Logging",
  "TableName": "Test",
  "RowsCopied": "6"
}
```

I want to group by on based of table name and rows copied.
I think I need to use dictionary inside dictionary.
Let me know if someone can help

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: There's loads of examples of how deserialize json into a list or dictionary. Here's one example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934360/how-to-deserialize-json-string-to-object-list-in-c-sharp-dot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I deserialize JSON to a simple Dictionary<string,string> in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net)